# Add class on click and then remove it on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Is there anyway to add a class on click and then remove that class when clicked again.

This is as far as I have got but everything I have tried to remove the class isn't working.

```
$(".meganav-toggle").click(function(){
$(".offcanvas-menu-left").addClass("activo");
```

Many thanks

Comment: You may want to use .toggleClass()

Comment: $(".meganav-toggle").click(function(){
$(".offcanvas-menu-left").toggleClass("activo");}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".meganav-toggle").click(function(){
  $(".offcanvas-menu-left").toggleClass("activo");
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's toggle class

```
$(".offcanvas-menu-left").toggleClass("active")
```

Comment: Thank you, would've accepted yours as the answer but someone just beat you to it.